Burnside's lemma formalizing counting
In the proof of Burnside's Lemma, there are two points that I see conceptually but would like more formal proof or explanation for.
The standard proof is something like:
$$
\begin{alignat}{1}
\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G}\left|X^g\right| & =\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G}|\{x \in X: g x=x\}|\\
& =\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{x \in X}|\{g \in G: g x=x\}|  \tag{*} \\
& =\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{x \in X}|\operatorname{Stab}(x)| \\
& =\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{x \in X} \frac{|G|}{|\operatorname{Orb}(x)|} \\
& =\sum_{x \in X} \frac{1}{|\operatorname{Orb}(x)|} \\
& =\sum_{\operatorname{Orb}(x) \in X / G}\left(\sum_{x \in \operatorname{Orb}(x)} \frac{1}{|\operatorname{Orb}(x)|}\right)  \tag{**} \\
& =\sum_{\operatorname{Orb}(x) \in X / G} 1 \\
& =|X / G|
\end{alignat}
$$
I know $(*)$ follows from counting cardinality of $\{(g,x) \in G \times X: g x=x\}$ along $g$ versus $x$.
I know $(**)$ follows from the fact that group actions are an equivalence relation, so the family of orbits ${O}$ partitions the set $X$, where $|O| = |X/G|$ with $X/G$ denoting set quotient of $X$ by underlying set of group $G$.
But how can I formalize these two points?

As for (*), browse for "Iverson bracket".

A more "formal" set-theoretic argument could go as follows.
For $g \in G$, denote $Fix(g) = \{x \in X : gx = x\}$.
(*): We can write $$\{(g,x) \in G \times X : gx = x\} = \bigcup_{g \in G} \left\{(g,x) 
 \in G \times X : gx = x\right\} = \bigcup_{g \in G} \{g\} \times Fix(g).$$
It should be clear that each $\{g\} \times Fix(g)$ has size $|Fix(g)|$, so the cardinality of the set above is $$\sum_{g \in G} |Fix(g)|.$$
Now similarly along $X$, we write $$\{(g,x) \in G \times X : gx = x\} = \bigcup_{x \in X} \left\{(g,x) 
 \in G \times X : gx = x\right\} = \bigcup_{x \in X} Stab_G(x) \times \{x\}.$$
so the cardinality of the set is $$\sum_{x \in X} |Stab_G(x)|.$$
So from these two different counts we conclude $\sum_{g \in G} |Fix(g)| = \sum_{x \in X} |Stab_G(x)|$.
For (**), we can write $$X = Orb(x_1) \cup \cdots \cup Orb(x_t)$$ where $Orb(x_i)$ are the distinct orbits. So you can rearrange the sum over $X$ as $$\sum_{x \in X} 1/|Orb(x)| = \sum_{i = 1}^t \sum_{y \in Orb(x_i)} 1/|Orb(y)|.$$
Then note that $|Orb(y)| = |Orb(x_i)|$ for all $y \in Orb(x_i)$ to complete the argument.

That is amazing. I spent hours trying this myself yesterday. I had the unions over the sets of ordered pairs, but the direct product with the singleton and then the set $X$ as union of orbits for the double sum is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much. I really appreciate you taking the time.
